# Switch branches in git between branches with/without a symbolic link directory

Tags: git

Branch A has a symbolic link directory under version control /symdir/
Branch B does not have it.

Q1: While in branch A will files beneath /symdir/ appear as untracked files? Id hope not.

Q2: When switching from branch A to branch B, would untracked files beneath /symdir/ cause issues? What I hope is that /symdir/ is removed in this situation.

Comment: Why not to try something in a small test repository?

Comment: A symbolic link is, fundamentally, a file - it's not a directory and it therefore cannot contain further files. This assumes you have an OS that supports symlinks, of course, and that you use the OS's inspection facilities in the way that makes the symbolic links show up *as* symbolic links. If you instruct the OS to take those files (the ones that symlinks really are) and *pretend* they are directories, you may see files "beneath" the link. Git makes sure to use the OS facilities that *don't* do that.

Comment: Note that because a symlink is a file, it can present the same classic "D/F" (directory/file) conflict as any other file. Suppose commit `a123456` has path `foo` as a file, and commit `b789abc` has paths `foo/file1` and/or `foo/file2`. Then Git must remove file `foo` to create folder/directory `foo` to hold `file1` and/or `file2`, when switching from `a123456` to `b789abc`.